# File saving dialogue: ask to rename instead of replace

Tags: files, gui, filemanager

When I want to save a file to an existing destination, the file saving manager (*“Save as”*) asks me whether I wish to **overwrite** the existing file with the same name. The button “yes” is preselected, so one accidential press on <kbd>space bar</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd> could lead to data loss. (Happened to me once in 2014, but then never again.)

This happens with every file saving dialogue (e.g. Firefox browser; all text editors; InkScape, LibreOffice tools, etc.)

I would prefer it to ask me to rename the file automatically or even rename it without asking me, so that I don't have to take care each time I want to save a file.

Comment: Hello, please mention what application you mean when you talking about this issue. IMO this is not an OS's option but application specific - text editor, file manager, etc.

Comment: @pa4080 E.g. Firefox web browser (I have already developed an `xdotool` script that does the saving and writing a timestamp at the beginning of a filename automatically.) But I wanted to know whether there is any way to make the file saver ask me to rename that file.

Comment: Please, [edit] and expand your question with the content you provided in your comment.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Done